# Realm RecyclerAdapter returns single item

Tags: java, android, json, realm

I am fetching data from json api I have set `PrimaryKey` as state. This is the `Json` data I am fetching:

```
records[
  {  
         "id":"192693681",
         "timestamp":"1500204608",
         "state":"Rajasthan",
         "district":"Rajasamand",
         "market":"Rajasamand",
         "commodity":"Sugar",
         "variety":"Shakkar",
         "arrival_date":"16/07/2017",
         "min_price":"4000",
         "max_price":"4100",
         "modal_price":"4050"
      },
      {  
         "id":"192693701",
         "timestamp":"1500204608",
         "state":"Rajasthan",
         "district":"Rajasamand",
         "market":"Rajasamand",
         "commodity":"Wheat",
         "variety":"Farmi",
         "arrival_date":"16/07/2017",
         "min_price":"1600",
         "max_price":"1650",
         "modal_price":"1625"
      },
      {  
         "id":"192693721",
         "timestamp":"1500204608",
         "state":"Rajasthan",
         "district":"Rajasamand",
         "market":"Rajasamand",
         "commodity":"Wheat",
         "variety":"Lokwan",
         "arrival_date":"16/07/2017",
         "min_price":"1550",
         "max_price":"1600",
         "modal_price":"1575"
      }
   ]
```

**This is my query to return the market data for every state:**

```
private void populateMarketData(String state){
        cityAdapter = new CityAdapter(mRealm.where(Records.class).equalTo(Constants.STATE, state).findAll(), this);
        cityRecyclerView.setAdapter(cityAdapter);
        Log.d(TAG, "Total Cities" + String.valueOf(cityAdapter.getData().size()));
        cityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**This is my query to return all commodities for the market with the states:**

```
 @Override
    public void onMarketClicked(String cityName) {
        tradeAdapter = new TradeAdapter(mRealm.where(Records.class)
                .equalTo(Constants.MARKET, cityName).findAll(), this);
        tradeRecyclerView.setAdapter(tradeAdapter);
    }
```

**This is `GcmTaskService` to update data in background service:**

```
Realm.init(mContext);
        List<Records> records = new MandiDataHandler().getMandiQuotes(url);
        SaveMandi saveMandi = new SaveMandi(state, records);
        Realm realm = new RealmController(getApplication()).getRealm();
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(saveMandi);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
```

**This is `DataHelper` to save the data from `Json` API**

```
@PrimaryKey
    private String state;

    private RealmList<Records> recordsRealmList = new RealmList<>();

    public SaveMandi(){}

    public SaveMandi(String state, List<Records> recordsList) {

        try {
            this.state = state;
            for (Records records: recordsList ) {
                records = new Records(records.getId(), DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                        Long.parseLong(records.getTimestamp())).toString(), records.getState(), records.getMarket(),
                        records.getCommodity(), records.getVariety(), records.getMin_price(), records.getMax_price());
                this.recordsRealmList.add(records);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem in my `RealmRecyclerView` it either returns single item when I set the `PrimaryKey` to state, else when I set the `PrimaryKey` to id it returns multiple duplicate data. I am not sure about where I might be wrong.

Comment: Did you get `RealmController` from http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/ ? because if so, you should remove it from your project and don't look back.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce then what do you suggest? The problem is I have repeated items on my json how can I parse them store as single object Kindly check here: https://pastebin.com/VcQkVTHt

Comment: `id` field in `Record` should be annotated with `@PrimaryKey`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ids for the same market are different that would still return multiple objects of same value right?

Comment: I do not understand the question

Answer (score 1):

You want to choose your `PrimaryKey` to be something that will only match when they are (what you deem as) "equal", much like an `equals()` method. If you put two `RealmObjects` with the same `PrimaryKey` into Realm only one of them will show up in Realm since there can only be one object for each distinct `PrimaryKey`.

For example if I have a `RealmObject a` with a `PrimaryKey` of `1` in realm and I put another `RealmObject b` with a `PrimaryKey` of `1` into Realm, `a` will be deleted with `b` since there can only be one object for every `PrimaryKey`.

A good tool to look through your Realm databases is [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/), I highly recommend it for debugging applications using Realm.

Comment: Now it returns multiple duplicate items from the RealmList.

Comment: I have checked through my json there are multiple items of same entity how can I save them as single object on my database? [link]https://pastebin.com/VcQkVTHt